# If DesiredCapabilities are obsolute in Selenium 3+, what to use instead for mobile web tests?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, appium, saucelabs

I am trying to learn how to write automated web tests in SauceLabs, and Visual Studio is telling me that DesiredCapabilities is deprecated in Selenium 3.  I figured out how to use `ChromeOptions` for desktop tests, but what about mobile web tests?  This works:

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
caps.SetCapability("deviceName", "iPhone 8 Simulator");
caps.SetCapability("deviceOrientation", "portrait");
caps.SetCapability("platformVersion", "12.0");
caps.SetCapability("platformName", "iOS");
caps.SetCapability("browserName", "Safari");
caps.SetCapability("username", SauceUsername);
caps.SetCapability("accessKey", SauceAccessKey);
caps.SetCapability("name", TestContext.TestName);
_driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub"),
            caps, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(600));
```

But I don't want to use a deprecated class.  I've used Selenium exensively in the past, but this my first time doing mobile web tests (no apps, just Safari/mobile Chrome).  Should I be using an Appium Driver instead?

Answer (score 4):

There will be a AppiumOptions() in a [future release of Appium v4](https://github.com/appium/appium-dotnet-driver/releases/tag/v4.0.0.2-beta) that will replace this. You can pull it down now and give it a try.

It will look something like this:

```
public void SimpleTest()
{
    var appiumOptions = new AppiumOptions();
    appiumOptions.AddAdditionalCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PlatformName, "Android");
    appiumOptions.AddAdditionalCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PlatformVersion, "7.1.1");

    appiumOptions.AddAdditionalCapability(MobileCapabilityType.FullReset, true);
    appiumOptions.AddAdditionalCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NewCommandTimeout, 60);

    appiumOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("testobject_api_key", "0D6C044F19D0442BA1E11C3FF087F6A6");
    appiumOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("username", SauceUser.Name);
    appiumOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("accessKey", SauceUser.AccessKey);
    //TODO first you must upload an app to Test Object so that you get your app key

    var rdcUrl = "https://us1.appium.testobject.com/wd/hub";
    var driver = new AndroidDriver<IWebElement>(new Uri(rdcUrl), appiumOptions);
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.ultimateqa.com");
    Console.WriteLine("");
    driver.Quit();
}
```

Comment: So there's currently no way to do this in a non-deprecated way using a stable Appium nuget?

Comment: Not that I know of. I think you got a few options I think. First, Use DesiredCaps and then switch over. Second, use the Beta version of the Nuget package, that way you'll be on the latest. Third, you could probably create a wrapper and call it something like DriverFactory that creates a mobile browser. Use that wherever. Then, when it's time to upgrade, you just update the implementation in one place, but the usage will remain the same. This is probably the best option to future proof your code

Answer (score -1):

I think you should try this with appium driver. Just download appium c# client and start. You can use following link to start with.

http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/mobile-web/